# Best way to save ever changing data

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a web app that consist of many rows. Each row has a label with "0" in it and a button. Pressing the button increments the label by 1.

The app starts with only one row, but the user can add as many as they want.

All of the values in the labels need to persist. So if a logged in user adds 10 rows, and presses the button on each row a few times, then next time they come back all of their values should have persisted. Herein lies the problem, as I am unsure of the most efficient way to save these values.

My first thought was to do an AJAX call on click of each button, but if the user spams the button to get to a certain value then I've made many superfluous calls. I could also save all rows every x seconds, but that could leave the user with incomplete data persistence if they alter a row and then leave before the next save triggers. I also thought of saving on unload, but that won't catch users who simply close their browsers or tab.

I'm using MVC, Jquery, C#, and MSSQL. My site and database live on the same server.

Comment: I believe that if you spam the button, it will cancel previous requests, so as long as you are sending up the total instead of just incrementing it, you would be fine.

Comment: What about placing the data in the session state and handling it on session end?

Comment: @drneel How about if they spam slowly (1 per second), that would give the ajax call plenty of time to call my server and initiate the database call.

Comment: Dont overthink this, it should save on each button click, the spam issue is the one you need to address, for example disable the button until you get a response

Comment: @sflancer06 That would help cut down the number of server -> database calls, which is one part of the issue. The other part is the best way to save via ajax.

Comment: 'note: if you wish to spam, please do not spam too slowly lest you should fail to get your spam across'

Comment: @meda I don't want to stop the spamming of the button. I want the user to go from 0 to their target number as quickly as possible using the button.

Comment: `if the user spams the button to get to a certain value then I've made many superfluous calls.` Check to see if any changes were made first.

Comment: If a user is having to click a button x times before they can get the row to contain value "x", then I think this could be a UI design issue.  Could you give the user a way to type in their desired value (# or rows, count within a row, etc) instead of making them "spam the button"?

Comment: @BateTech The user does have that option, but they also have the option to spam.

Comment: Can someone explain the negatives on my question? I thought it was a rather good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't disable the button as it might harm usability - I don't know the concrete context you're working in but if you're concerned about button-spamming then this might be a valid scenario for the user. A service call might take some time depending on the underlying network and the distance between client and server. From a user's perspective the app is reacting fast and smoothly if inputs can be delivered within 10 to 100 milliseconds - a goal that can be harmed if you perform a service call every time the user presses the button.

A common pattern to avoid this is to use a timer: when the user presses the button a timer is started that runs for maybe 400 to 500 milliseconds:

- If the user provides new input before the timer reaches the end of the interval the timer should be restarted
- If the timer did signal the end of the interval without any further input from the user you can savely make your service call.

I've used this pattern in my own solutions. I got the time values from Jeff Johnson's excellent book [Designing with the mind in mind](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2014/05/designing-with-the-mind-in-mind-simple-guide-to-understanding-user-interface-design-guidelines-secon.php).

Comment: I like this option. Might want to also add something that says: if x actions have occurred without a save or some total time period has elapsed since last save (super spam user is going for 5000 clicks), then go ahead and trigger a save on that max interval.